# Is there any editable Auto-Increment besdies IDENTITY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The reason I need this for is that I made a column on my table called display_order, for now it's smallint and the numbers were pre-determined.

However, when I insert a new record with my software I don't know how to get the highest number in that column and add 1, so I thought about the possibility of an auto-incremented column where if I change 8 to 9 it will change everything else accordingly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Let me just see if I understand your question. You want your primary key to be auto-increment in all instances except those that it shouldn't be auto-increment?

Comment: And why can't you simply switch the column to be an identity column now?

Comment: Um, because identity columns are not editable? At least there's no easy way to edit it, via MSSQL there's a way, but via code might be more difficult to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > However, when I insert a new record with my software I don't know how to get the highest number in that column and add 1,

```
Insert MyTable( display_order, .... )
Select (
        Select Max(display_order) + 1
        From MyTable As T1
        ), ...
From MyTable
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this. If display_order is user settable, then I would simply assume relative values. Thus, it wouldn't matter if a user added two values with a display_order = 0. If you really want to go the extra mile and provide the ability to resequence the display_order, you could do it like so:

```
Update MyTable
Set display_order = Z.NewSeq
From    (
        Select PKCol
            , Row_Number() Over ( Order By display_order ) As NewSeq
        From MyTable
        ) As Z
    Join MyTable As T
        On T.PKCol = Z.PKCol
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is "No" `IDENTITY` is the only  auto incrementing capability (and these columns are not updatable)

But if this is a `display_order` field can't you just make it `float` to allow you to insert items between other items rather than having to shift all other items down to create a gap?

Answer (score 1):

Because you only get one `IDENTITY` column per table, I would probably use a trigger or other mechanism (if there's a centralized insertion stored proc) to default it to one more than the highest number in the table if not provided.  This avoids having to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` or anything like that.